# Webpage refresh without changing iframe src

Tags: php, session

I have an iframe on my webpage:

```
<iframe name="crm_frame" id="crm_frame" src="<?php echo $iframe_src; ?>" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and i have tried to add a session variable for the requested_uri

```
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'index.php')
{
    $_SESSION["iframe_page"] = 'dashboard.php';
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["iframe_page"] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

and then set the `$iframe_src` variable for to echo in the SRC of the iframe code

```
if($_SESSION["iframe_page"] == '')
{
    $iframe_src = 'dashboard.php';
}
else
{
    $iframe_src = $_SESSION["iframe_page"];
}
```

but its not saving the sesison variable.

any ideas?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is tricky. Are you sure you can compare it to 'index.php'? Its value is probably '/' or '/index.php'. Besides, are you using `session_start()` on every page? Your code seems valid otherwise.

Comment: just realised its saving the session variable however when i refresh the page, it sets the session variable back to index.php. index.php is the only page ever seen in the address bar, all the other pages are in the iframe. so any ideas how i can keep the previous session variable even if the page is refreshed